# Admeasuring vs. measuring

Tags: meaning, word-choice, legalese

I often find lawyers describing an area as “admeasuring xx square feet”.

How is ***ad***measuring any different from just plain *measuring*, or do ***ad***measuring and *measuring* mean the same thing?

Comment: It is in the [dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/admeasure) and here for "[admeasuring](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/admeasuring)".

Comment: To Rathony: Sir, I have reworded the question so that it could fit the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Admeasure*** means to measure something in a formal or exact way. It has to some extent fallen into disuse, but it is still a term applied in shipping, marine architecture, and in a few other fields.

Here are one or two fairly recent examples from the OED.

> 1999   J. Kretschmer Flirting with Mermaids (2003) 116   Country Girl
>   had not been through the canal previously and thus required an
>   admeasurement... Once admeasured, you pay your fees..and schedule a
>   transit
>
> 1997   Indian Express (Nexis) 8 Oct.   The government published a
>   special notification declaring that land admeasuring 365 hectares had
>   been excluded from the forest area.
>
> 2008   D. G. Brown How to make Money with your Captain's License 89
>   U.S. Coast Guard regulations require all U.S. commercial vessels
>   admeasuring more than five gross tons to be documented.
>
> 1994   St. Petersburg (Florida) Times (Nexis) 20 Nov. b1   Although
>   the report does not admeasure blame, the investigators question the
>   actions of each captain.

.

Answer (score 1):

It means "to measure out" or "apportion," if you will. It is in the dictionary. Here's the link:

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/admeasure?s=t